# What is SQL Injection Attacks .? Some Tips on How to Prevent Them With basic Examples

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection)

I'm working in one PHP project with MYSQL database.
I read about SQL injection but would like to have some basic example.
What would be happen if attacks.?

I'm new in this topic.
Thanks

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A1

Comment: Maybe start [here](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413320/basic-sql-injections

Comment: See also http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-injection-myths-and-fallacies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically if you have a SQL call like this:

```
"DELETE FROM Users WHERE InputtedName = '$name'"
```

People could input on the form: `My Name' OR InputtedName != 'My Name`

This would result in the following SQL Call, when $name is replaced with the inputted name from a form:

```
"DELETE FROM Users WHERE InputtedName = 'My Name' OR InputtedName != 'My Name'"
```

That would delete everything in your table! Not good! So to prevent this, you should use the mysql_real_escape_string() function on all user inputted data.

Comment: And as you could imagine, this can be used in many ways to alter information that shouldn't be altered.

Comment: `' OR '1'='1` is even more used (nobody knows field names easily)

Answer (score 4):

There is a lot to tell, but I'll just say:

- You should have a look here : [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/about.html).

As a summary :

[image]

Comment: -1 This doesn't help a beginner understand the vulnerability or the defense.

Comment: I think [their example](http://bobby-tables.com/about.html) is quite clear to everybody.

Comment: Fair enough, I will reverse my -1 if you unlock your post (just edit it once).

Comment: Changed the Bobby Table's link directly to the example related to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Say I have a table "Users" and someone is registering for an account on my site. They enter their username as `'); drop table Users` which would terminate my INSERT statement early and cause the users table to be deleted.

A good rule of thumb is to "sanitize" any data you receive from a user. To do this you'll want to use PHP's [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) (deprecated). An even better option is [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) though they're longer and not always graceful.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('select name from users where id = ?');
$stmt->bind_param($id,'s');
$id = 'some_id';
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($name);
$stmt->fetch(); //variable $name now has the value of the first result
```

Comment: All mysql_* functions (including `mysql_real_escape_string`) are deprecated. [Your options are MySQLi or PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)